# How do you get the access token expiration time from aws cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, devops, amazon-cognito

I tried getting the access token expiration times like this:

```
aws cognito-idp describe-user-pool-client --user-pool-id  [cognito user pool id] --client-id [cognito app id]
```

but it only gives me the refresh token's expiration time. Is there a security reason for excluding the access token expiration time or did aws cli just not get to returning this yet?

Comment: It should: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeUserPoolClient.html. Maybe it does not report it when the value is the default one?

Comment: Yeah, turns out you have to update aws to the latest version and then toggle the  access token expiration time value from the default (if you want default values) to a new value and back to the default for it to register and return